# Goroutines sharing an array channel : trying to solve data race

Tags: arrays, go, parallel-processing, channel

I try to write a complex program with parallel goroutines. It is my first program with channels ;)  Each goroutine returns an array and, unfortunately, the result is "random". If I run 10 times the program, I have 10 different results :(

This is an over simplification of my program, the results is good (maybe because it is too simple) but when I run it with -race argument, there is 4 data races.

I tried to had a close() function but it did not worked.

May you help me to find the mistake ? Thank you very much in advance !

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"
import "strconv"


func cat_strings(a int, b string) []string{
    var y []string

    j := strconv.Itoa(a)
    y = append(y, j)
    y = append(y, b)
    return y
}

func main() {
    var slice []string
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var x []string

    queue := make(chan []string, 10)

    wg.Add(10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            x = cat_strings(i, "var")
            queue <- x
        }(i)

    }
    //close(queue)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for t := range queue {
            slice = append(slice, t...)
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

Comment: You put 10 things into a channel in an undefined order, so I'm not sure what you expected to happen here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's two pieces to this fix, don't share the slices between goroutines, and then range over `queue` synchronously in `main`.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

func cat_strings(a int, b string) []string {
    var y []string

    j := strconv.Itoa(a)
    y = append(y, j)
    y = append(y, b)
    return y
}

func main() {
    var slice []string
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    queue := make(chan []string, 10)

    wg.Add(10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            queue <- cat_strings(i, "var")
        }(i)

    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(queue)
    }()

    for t := range queue {
        slice = append(slice, t...)
    }

    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

There's no reason for the extra `x` slice you're sharing between goroutines. If each goroutine needs another slice, define a new one for each. Sharing a single slice is always going to require extra synchronization.

The other race is between the goruoutine appending from `queue` to the `slice` slice, and the final `fmt.Println`. There's no reason for those be concurrent since you don't want to print until all values have been read, so finish the for-range loop entirely before printing the final value.